# Crystal Reports 2013 compatibility with Classic ASP

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic, crystal-reports

How to fix Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a01ad' ActiveX component can't create object: 'CrystalReports.ObjectFactory'?

I am using a Windows 2012 server where the Classic ASP application is deployed.
Crystal Reports 2013 is installed on the server.

The error occurs in the code below:

`Set ObjectFactory = CreateObject("CrystalReports.ObjectFactory")`

Comment: Why not just call it from a asp.net page rather than asp-classic page?   That error means there is a DLL or dependency which it can't find.

Comment: Thanks Dijkgraaf. But our entire application is in classic asp. We don't have any developer version of the code. Is there any setting that I can do on the server to fix the error?

Comment: You need to identify what DLL is missing as per this article  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/194801